# How to Double Click on plain text in webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, double-click

I have moved mouse pointer on to a certain plain text (a word) by this:

```
    Robot robot1 = new Robot();
    robot1.mouseMove(430,628); //location of the text/word
```

Now I just need to double click so that my text/word gets selected. Can you help me on how to do that?
I tried action builder without element ID (as it is a plain text) for doubleclick, which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the case for Selenium Actions:-)

```
new Actions(driver).doubleClick().build().perform(); //clicks on the current mouse position
```

However it would be nicer if you could specify the element which you want to click on

```
new Actions(driver).doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.id("id")).build().perform();
```

Comment: Apparently tried the first one, as plain texts does not have id. But the word is not getting selected :(